# Invalid INDX entries for $I30 on NTFS harddisk

Tags: windows, hex

While parsing my NTFS formatted hard disk, I found some invalid entries of INDX while Windows is still able to list all the root directory contents!

The structure of the Index Record in *NTFS 3.1* is clear ([NTFS doc](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf)):

```
Offset      Description
-------------------------------------
0x00        MFT Reference of the file
0x08        Size of the index entry
0x0A        Offset to the filename
...
0x52        Filename
...
```

However, I found some entries where their size is faulty as well as their MFT Reference (which is a bunch of zeros)!

I enclose a screenshot that shows a part of INDX along side with their text representations where each line is of width `0x20`. I highlighted the faulty part.

[image: The invalid entries of INDX]

The figure shows that entries were parsed rationally until the last correct entry at `0x0628`:

- MFT Reference (8 bytes): `66 30 00 00 00 00 01 00`
- Size of entry (2 bytes): `70 00`
  So the entry ends at `0x0697`.

Thereafter, things got weird! Entries at `0x0698`:

- MFT Reference (8 bytes): `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` Seems invalid
- Size of entry (2 bytes): `10 00` Of course invalid because the size is less than the entry structure minimum size that includes the filename at `0x52` for instance.

For me, it seems that "Buziol Games" was a deleted folder on the root directory of the harddisk, I am not sure. Anyway, Windows explorer is not facing troubles on listing the contents.

Do anybody understand how does it work? How do Windows continue parsing?

**EDIT**: In addition, please find the hex dump as a pure text on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kksNZQ5t)

Comment: what have you highlighted the INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY should be preceded by INDEX_HEADER which should have a magic signature INDX  i don't see a INDX magic sign in your screen shot ?   8200a000  49 4e 44 58    offset to index entries @ 18 8200a010  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-28 00 00 00  ie 0x28

Comment: @blabb, indeed the INDEX_HEADER is at address zero. I already parsed several INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY (ies) without any problem. My question is about the invalid INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY at address 0x0698. Anyway, the whole INDX (including INDEX_HEADER) is found at the pastebin attached

Comment: if that was the last entry with an mft reference of 0 then size would be 10 is correct iirc it is mentioned in the pdf you linked somewhere  you cna also check this thread http://www.woodmann.com/forum/showthread.php?15188-NTFS-MFT-Internals/page3&highlight=ntfs

Comment: from your pastebin the size of index entries is 690 it matches with 620+70 = 

690 so any reason to  parse further ? Offset(h) 00 01 02 03

0000001C  90 06 00 00  ....

Comment: offset 58+52 $Attrdef  0xc0+52 $BadCluster 0x128+52 $bitmap 0x188+52 $boot  0x1e8+52 $extend 0x248+52 $logfile  0x2b0+52 $Mft  0x310+53 $MftMirr 0x378+52 $Secure  0x3d8+52 $upcase 0x438+52 $Volume  0x498+52 . (dot directory)  0x4f0+52 Ahmad 0x550+52 AutoExec.bat  5c0+52 boot.ini  and buziol games

Comment: You are perfect @blabb. Thank you. But I still have two points: (1) the size of index entries which is 0x0690 is relative to 0x18 which means it should end at 0x06A8, Right? (2) What about the remaining folders? I still have a lot of folders which are not parsed yet such as "Program Files", "Windows", "Documents and Settings" and others? Please note that there exist only one datarun.

Comment: yes it will end at 6a8 with a mft refernce 0 and size 0x10   remaining folder would be in another index entry you may need to find them i added an answer (most of them from long gone memory have a look and ask if there are any queries)

Comment: @blabb would you please explain much more the second point noting that **there exist only one datarun** that points directly to this INDX. How to find the _another index entry_. I feel that there is something odd! Moreover I didn't understant this sentence, would you clarify it please "most of them from long gone memory have a look and ask if there are any queries". Thank you.

Comment: that means i don't remember much and it has been very long time that i looked actually into the ntfs internals and its structure so unless asked a specific question it would be very difficult for me to put a coherent answer to dataruns $mft FILE0 etc look at the link i posted in my earlier comment i vaguely remember posting a pdf showing how to carve a file from non resident multiple dataruns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY should be preceded by INDEX_HEADER with the magic signature **INDX**

without the header deciphering the INDEX_RECORD_ENTRIES is difficult as shown in your screen shot

the following observations are based on the pastebin dump you edited in later

i converted the hex to binary with a bat file thus

```
rem make a copy 
copy %1 %2
rem compare both
fc %1 %2
rem dump the first line for visualizing
head -1 %2
rem strip the address,colon and space 
rem this is to make it compatible with xxd input
sed s/.*:\x20//g %2 > %3
rem dump the ripped hex file first line 
head -1 %3
rem convert hex to binary 
xxd -r -p %3 > %4
rem check the size and compare with word count
rem both should be same 
ls -l %4
wc -w %3
```

executing the bat file on the downloaded pastebin dump

```
C:\indx>converthextobin.bat indx_$i30_dump.txt indxhex.txt indxstripped.txt indxbin.bin

C:\indx>rem make a copy
C:\indx>copy indx_$i30_dump.txt indxhex.txt
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\indx>rem compare both
C:\indx>fc indx_$i30_dump.txt indxhex.txt
Comparing files indx_$i30_dump.txt and INDXHEX.TXT
FC: no differences encountered

C:\indx>rem dump the first line for visualizing
C:\indx>head -1 indxhex.txt
0000: 49 4E 44 58 28 00 09 00 D2 92 87 08 00 00 00 00

C:\indx>rem strip the address,colon and space
C:\indx>rem this is to make it compatible with xxd input
C:\indx>sed s/.*:\x20//g indxhex.txt  1>indxstripped.txt

C:\indx>rem dump the ripped hex file first line
C:\indx>head -1 indxstripped.txt
49 4E 44 58 28 00 09 00 D2 92 87 08 00 00 00 00

C:\indx>rem convert hex to binary
C:\indx>xxd -r -p indxstripped.txt  1>indxbin.bin

C:\indx>rem check the size and compare with word count
C:\indx>rem both should be same
C:\indx>ls -l indxbin.bin
-rw-rw-rw-  1 HP 0 6656 2017-07-22 15:20 indxbin.bin
C:\indx>wc -w indxstripped.txt
6656 indxstripped.txt
```

now that we have a binary form we can start exploring

lets dump the INDEX_HEADER and verify

```
@echo off
xxd -s00 -g4 -l4 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s04 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s06 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s08 -g8 -l8 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s16 -g8 -l8 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s24 -g4 -l4 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s28 -g4 -l4 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s32 -g4 -l4 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s36 -g1 -l1 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s37 -g3 -l3 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s40 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin
```

executed we get the INDEX_HEADER

```
C:\indx>dumpindxheader.bat
0000000: 494e4458                             INDX
0000004: 2800                                     (.
0000006: 0900                                     ..
0000000: 494e445828000900                   INDX(...
0000010: 0000000000000000                   ........
0000018: 40000000                             @...
000001c: 90060000                             ....
0000020: e80f0000                             ....
0000024: 00
0000025: 000000                                 ...
0000028: 1e02                                     ..
```

we can see the INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY relative to HEADER_OFFSET is 0x40 (i haven't tried to control the Endiannes in xxd output)

so the INDEX_RECORD_ENTRY (terminology may be incorrect ) starts at 0x40+0x18 = 0x58
it is a variable sized structure padded appropriately to boundaries

dumping the record entry

```
@echo off
xxd -s88 -g8 -l8 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s96 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s98 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s100 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s102 -g2 -l2 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -c8 -s104 -g8 -l64 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s168 -g1 -l1 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s169 -g1 -l1 indxbin.bin &^
xxd -s170 -g1 -l22 indxbin.bin
```

executing the bat file

```
C:\indx>dumpindxrecordentry.bat
0000058: 0400000000000400                   ........
0000060: 6800                                     h.
0000062: 5200                                     R.
0000064: 0000                                     ..
0000066: 0000                                     ..
0000068: 0500000000000500  ........
0000070: d07fa49ac58cd201  ........
0000078: d07fa49ac58cd201  ........
0000080: d07fa49ac58cd201  ........
0000088: d07fa49ac58cd201  ........
0000090: 0090000000000000  ........
0000098: a08c000000000000  ........
00000a0: 0600000000000000  ........
00000a8: 08                                               .
00000a9: 03                                               .
00000aa: 24 00 41 00 74 00 74 00 72 00 44 00 65 00 66 00  $.A.t.t.r.D.e.f.
00000ba: 00 00 00 00 00 00                                ......
```

the size 68 is relative to self so the next entry would be at 
0x58+0x68 == 0xc0

the offset to file name is relative to self so file name would be at 
0x58+0x52 = 0xaa as dumped

so you can now go ahead by dumping the next entry by providing the appropriate seek address to xxd viz 0xc0 or 0n192

the last entry is at 0x628 whose size is 0x70 so it ends at 0x698

the very last entry is 0x10 bytes long with an mft reference 0

> quoted from the pdf linked in your original post
>   last entry has a size of 0x10 (just large enough for the flags (and a
>   mft ref of zero)

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000690                          00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ........
000006A0  10 00 00 00 02 00 00 00                          ........
```